# Porting ANSI code on Solaris/Linux to Windows Server 2012

Tags: c, windows, unix, post

The requirement is to port a legacy C code (~1.5 million LOC)  running on Solaris/Linux to Windows Server 2012. (Currently works on Cygwin but performance is way below as on Linux)

1. The C code is making a lot of underlying Linux system calls, Linux IPC mechanisms, Shared memory, Signals, Pipes. Semaphores etc...
2. Need to migrate the supporting Perl/Shell code also onto Windows equivalents.

Is there a 1-1 mapping for each of the Linux system calls especially the fork() and IPC mechanisms, Shared memory, Signals, Pipes. Semaphores etc...?

What are the complexities and best approach to such a port?

Would using a tool help fasten the porting process. Any specific tools that would help?

Would there be a lot of manual re-write?

How can one arrive at the effort at a high level?

Appreciate inputs and advice.

Thanks,

Sadananda

Comment: It's really not possible to give concrete advice here without a lot more familiarity with your code than we have.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the current state of the affairs, but few years ago I was able to complete a similar task with [Windows Services for Unix](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463212.aspx).

The only caveat is that Linux is not Unix, at least not Unix from the MS point of view. Expect a number of hiccups.

Comment: Is Interix supported on Windows Server 2012

Comment: As I said, I have no idea on what's going on now. Last time I touched it was 2007.